# Can't get Minikube to run on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I installed Minikube on Windows 10 but can't get it to run. I tried to start it with:

```
 minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

The first error was:

```
[HYPERV_NO_VSWITCH] create: precreate: no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this command to run.
```

I then searched on Google and found the solution to this error with this page:

```
https://www.codingepiphany.com/2019/01/04/kubernetes-minikube-no-external-vswitch-found/
```

I then fixed the problem by defining a vswitch but I got this error:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Minikube"
o   minikube v1.0.1 on windows (amd64)
$   Downloading Kubernetes v1.14.1 images in the background ...
>   Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...

!   Unable to start VM: create: creating: exit status 1

*   Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
-   https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
```

This is a pretty generic error. What do I do to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: can you run same command with `-v=10` parameter and update original post with output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Virtual Switch in the HyperV GUI ins Windows and then run it with 
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"

Please see the configuration details in this link 
https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem just now.
Unable to understand the note given by cmd, I tried open the minikube VM **via the Hyper-V GUI**, and the GUI provided me with a more comprehensible note: **"memory is not adequate"**—— exactly this note helped me to know the problem. I then closed Docker VM (I had opened before), which must have taken a large amount of memory, and started minikube in cmd again, the minikube VM just started as expected.

In a word, this is a problem of **limited memory**